# Close After Saving All Instances (Unknown #) of Open Word Documents With Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

With Excel VBA, how could I go about closing (after saving) all instances of Microsoft Word files (.docx) currently open on my computer? This would be with a button push.

I have this code which works to close one. How could I adapt it to close an unknown number?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim objWord As Object

    Do Until GetObject(, "Word.Application") Is Nothing
        Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        Debug.Print objWord

        objWord.Quit False
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on your question, but this code will cycle through multiple instances of Word (which is different than multiple documents) closing all docs in that instance without prompting to save. It's lightly tested:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim objWord As Object

'avoid error if no Word instances are open
On Error Resume Next
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
Do Until objWord Is Nothing
   Debug.Print objWord
   objWord.Quit False
   'start from scratch
   Set objWord = Nothing
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Doug. You understood my question just fine ... your solution was exactly what I was looking for! The only thing that may have been missed is the need to save the documents (Word documents) before closing them. A simple change from objword.quit False to True took care of that!

Thanks!!